# How to draw lines with Java for functions like f(x,y)

Tags: java, graphics, japplet

I am new to graphics with Java and I have a GUI that is incomplete.  What I need to do is to  plot functions like:

```
f(x,y) = 100 × (x²-y)² + (1-x)²
```

where `-2.048 < x,y < 2.048`.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you mean to plot `f(x,y)=0`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776728/plotting-equation-to-cartesian-plane

Comment: *"Can anyone please help?"*  Where are you stuck?

Comment: how can i use gdrawline to draw a function where x and y change values!
Heuster no actually, i wanna maximize the function, so in order to give the user an idea on how the function varies i thought it would be vigourous to plot it!

Comment: @JAZak No offence, but that doesn't make sense mathematically. You want to show a 3-dimensional curve (see the [plot by Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[100%28x^2-y%29^2%2B%281-x%29^2%2C+{x%2C+-2048%2C2048}%2C+{y%2C+-2048%2C+2048}])) by a 2-dimensional line. That implies you'll have to limit one of the dimensions.